# Problem building the signal interceptor during the Molecular Level?

Tags: fallout-4

I have a problem in building the signal interception, it always tells me to use the power from one grid, which I've done but it doesn't work at all.

Is this a bug or there is a certain way of connecting them?

Answer (score 6):

You need all components to be linked together with wires, except the pad which goes underneath the emitter.

The safest way to be sure everything is linked properly is to connect all three large generators (needed to get the required 27 energy), the console and the dish to the emitter.

Your layout should look like this:

[image: Signal Interceptor layout]

Be sure your pad is snapped correctly under the emitter. It will draw its power automatically from it, you don't need to use a wire.

**NOTE:** If you decided to build the Signal Interceptor with the BoS at the Boston Airport, you will need to get rid of the rugs in order to snap the emitter to the pad.

With rugs (Cannot place it correctly):
[image: Can't build the emitter with rugs]

Without rugs (Snaps into place):
[image: Can build the emitter]

Failing to place the pad under the emitter will trigger the generic "make sure they are on the same grid" sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to ensure that "power is coming from one grid" is to plug them into each other. If you connect each component of the signal interceptor together with wire then they'll all be on the same grid.