# Quest mark on my workshop in the "Molecular Level"

Tags: fallout-4

For some reason on the quest "Molecular Level" there is a green quest mark on it and nothing else. I have chosen the BoS and I have completed the interceptor but Proctor Ingram wont let me power it up because of the quest mark on the work shop. Please Help so I can continue.

Comment: When you view the quest status in your Pip-Boy, what does it say to do for the next step? It sounds like it wants you to retrieve something from your workshop or build something in a settlement via the workshop.

Comment: it says power up the interceptor

Comment: The quest marker for the Molecular Level is on the workshop because you have to build things.

Comment: but what? do you

Comment: Are all the things wired together, and does your settlement have a green power indicator on the top ribbon?

Comment: Top ribbon? ...

Comment: I got it I had to build 2 signal interceptors thx

Comment: You don't need to build two. But you have to wire everything up together. More details [in this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/245102/130874)

Comment: When you're in workshop mode, there are a bunch of icons with numbers at the top. This kind of thing is sometimes called a ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

If a settlement workshop is highlighted as a quest objective, that usually means **you either need to build something in a settlement in build mode or retrieve an item from the workshop**.

In your case, it sounds like you need to power up the interceptor. Try building a power-generating structure, then connecting a piece of wire between it and the interceptor.

- Open "build mode" in your settlement.
- Go to "Power" > "Generators", select an option from the list, and place it near your interceptor.
- Hover over the power generator. In the toolbar at the bottom of the screen, there should be an option to press a button to "attach wire" (<kbd>space</kbd> on PC, <kbd>Y</kbd> on XBox One).
- Next, hover over the interceptor and press the same button to connect the other end of the wire to the interceptor.

Here's a video tutorial that teaches you the basics of power: