# The Molecular Level Quest help

Tags: fallout-4

When I put the Signal Interceptor together and do everything correctly the pad still wont power does anyone know what to do?

Comment: In questions like this - you either encountered a bug, or you in fact did not do everything correctly. Identifying which case it is and providing help both require you to provide more information about the precise steps you took.

Comment: You can look at [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/245102/130874) on a similar question for an easy setup. If you do exactly this simple setup and it still does not power up, then it's a different kind of problem.

Comment: We've had a few questions about people having trouble with this. Try reading them over and seeing if anything works. If you try all that stuff, and nothing works, say that in the question and we'll go from there. I just had an issue with this last night, and was able to fix it by storing and replacing the console and the wire hooked to it.

Answer (score 1):

Wire up 3 large generators.

"Three Large Generators should be enough to power this entire operation if you have the supplies. You’ll need 27 total. For this, we used three Large Generators, with each of them producing 10 Power. You can use whatever works, but we found this to be the most straightforward way to complete this task." - ([Source](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/fallout-4-the-molecular-level-power-up-the-signal-interceptor))

Then talk to Sturges and tell him to make it happen.

"Again, in our case this was Sturges, but you’ll have to speak with the faction scientist that represents the crew you asked for assistance. At this point in the quest you shouldn’t have any trouble, however." - ([Source](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/fallout-4-the-molecular-level-power-up-the-signal-interceptor))

Comment: If you can't make 3 large generators because you don't have the Science perk, I did it with 2 medium generators, 1 windmill and a couple of small ones all connected to eachother.

Comment: I just kept throwing medium generators at it until it turned green.